# I have to print the month & year from the entered month/year to current one

Tags: php, html, date

The problem is when i entered month 12 & year 2015,it print till the 2016's 12 month instead of 1st month.
(Hint in any language will be great as it is all about logic so i am adding C & JAVA in tag)
Here is the code

```
<form method="GET" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="year" value="Enter Year" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="month" value="Enter MOnth" /></td>

                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <?php $joinmonth=$_GET['month'];
    $joinyear=$_GET['year'];

    $currentmonth=date('m');

    $currentyear=date('Y');
    if(isset($_GET['submit']))
    {
    for($i=$joinyear;$i<=$currentyear;$i++)
    {
                 for ($j = $joinmonth; $j <=12 ; $j++) {

        a:
            if ($i <= $currentyear) {
                if ($j == 12) {
                    echo "MOnth ".$j." & year ".$i."<br><br>";
                    $j = 1;
                    $i++;
                    goto a;
                } 
                else {
                    echo "MOnth ".$j." & year ".$i."<br><br>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: value of $joinmonth and $joinyear????

Comment: from two text box & we will enter it

Comment: please provide the test value??? joinmonth = 12, joinyear = 2015 ????

Comment: @devpro i updated the code & added html part too... & yes you can take join month 12 & joinyear 2015 for testing

Comment: yes, i have checked, and update an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will give your join month and year and ist month and year:

```
$joinmonth=12;
$joinyear=2015;

$currentmonth=date('m');

$currentyear=date('Y');

if(isset($_GET['submit']))
{
    for($i=$joinyear;$i<=$currentyear;$i++)
    {
        for ($j = $joinmonth; $j <=12 ; $j++) 
        {
            a:
            if ($i <= $currentyear) 
            {
                if ($j == 12) 
                {
                    echo "MOnth ".$j." & year ".$i."<br><br>";
                    $j = 1;
                    $i++;
                    goto a;
                } 
                elseif($j == $currentmonth) 
                {
                    echo "MOnth ".$j." & year ".$i."<br><br>";
                }              
            }
            return;                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it only 12 number month  not anyother & it is the same output i am getting with my code

Comment: which is wrong...correct output will be month 12 & year 2015....month 01 & year 2016 ...as current year is 2016 & month is 01

Comment: @SSangeet: expected result same? 2 record join info current info??

Comment: read the question dude,we have to print the month/year from the entered month/year to current(today) one...

Comment: by the way i find the answer